# How to push data into array in php?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two same variables

```
$newRow = $this->db->table(self::TABLE_NAME);
$rows = $this->db->table(self::TABLE_NAME);
```

with data from database

i want somehow push filtred data from variable $rows to variable $ newRow using this function but i dont know how to push it there

```
   $rows = $this->db->table(self::TABLE_NAME);
if ($showActiveOnly == 1) {
        $newRow = $rows->where(array('status' => 'dodano'));
    }
    $rows = $this->db->table(self::TABLE_NAME);
if($showNotAdded == 1){
        $newRow = $rows->where(array('status' => 'nedodano'));
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you know how to create empty variable newRow but with same proptreties as i have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should understand what is the resultant output type of the data. If it is a `Illuminate\Support\Collection` then you can use `$newRow->merge($rows);`

If it is an array type then you can use `$rows = array_merge($newRow, $rows);`.

More information available below:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php
- https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections